# ImportError: Could not import settings (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named setting

Tags: django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, plesk, centos6

I'm going through the "example" project into production on a VPS **CentOS 6** (with **Plesk**) with **python2.7**, **mod_wsgi**, **Django 1.6** I have proven many configurations and I always get error "No module named settings" or "No module named Unipath". Not that I have wrong or I'm missing. Thanks and regards.

My vhost.conf:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/
Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/media/

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example.com/example.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My example.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/example'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I put my project via ftp into : /var/www/vhosts/example.com/

```
example.com/
      example(project)
          settings.py
          urls.py
          ...
      app
          models.py
          forms.py
          views.py
          ...
      templates
      httpdocs
      example.wsgi
      manage.py
```

Thanks again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go read the official Django documentation on how to setup things for mod_wsgi:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

You are not setting the Python module search path or DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as described in that document.

Answer (score 2):

Your settings are in example app so it should be:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'example.settings'
```

Comment: I try with this and same error :( Settings are inside of project example sorry

Answer (score 0):

### Use `WSGIDaemonProcess` & `WSGIProcessGroup`

You can solve this issue by setting the `python-path` in `apache2` config
to point at your django project directory

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/
Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/media/

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/example.com/example.wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess example.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/var/www/vhosts
WSGIProcessGroup example.com

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

- Edited to switch from *Embedded mode* to *Daemon mode*. Credit to  *[Graham Dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton)* which is the author of [this blog post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html) and also commented about it.

Comment: Except that you should not be using embedded mode. Use daemon mode of mod_wsgi and it is the ``python-path`` option to ``WSGIDaemonProcess``. Repeat, you should never be using embedded mode unless you are stuck with Windows.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thanks for the comment, i also read [your blog post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html). i wasn't aware of daemon mode. thank you!  edited my answer